# How can I bump other users' unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, bump

I'm looking around for answers to my questions on several Stack Exchange sites and the good boy that I am I don't want to ask duplicate questions.

Often I find that there are other people who asked the same questions, sometimes years earlier, but still don't have an answer. I'd figure I could bump these back to top, but if I don't have enough rep for a edit (or comment), how would I do that?

Or, in that case, I should just post a 'newer' version of the same question?

Comment: Ironically, the edit Cai just made to this question made it less clear. The "how to bump unanswered questions"-question is asked a lot by people wanting to bump their own unanswered question. In this case it is about _other_ peoples questions.

Comment: Apologies if you think my edit made it less clear, you can always [edit] again yourself if your unhappy with an edit. The main reason for my edit was changing Stack Overflow to Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow is one specific site, Stack Exchange is the network of sites)

Comment: Aye, I saw that! That was an honest mistake on my part. My comment was mostly about the title which I see you already restored (thx!) I was just looking for an option to comment on a edit, but I think there's no such thing

Comment: You can't comment on an edit directly no, but you can @reply to an editor which will notify them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but if I don't have enough rep for a edit

You can always *suggest* an edit. If accepted, it will bump the question.

Note that commenting doesn't bump - so even if you *could* comment, the only person/s notified would be the post OP and whomever you chose to @ comment to.

Comment: Ok! I suggested the edit, is this the best way, then?

Answer (score 3):

It's not bumping but if you just want to draw attention to a question then an alternative is to use the `share` button beneath it to advertise it, for example, to your Twitter following.

You should never post a 'newer' version of the same question.

Seven ways to 'revive' old questions, depending on your reputation at the time, are listed in [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4011/115) to [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers)

Comment: `You should never post a 'newer' version of the same question.` < I figured, that's why I asked :) advertising in my case wouldn't really work, because I come to these communities because no one I have contact with can help me with these questions