# How do I reopen a question with has an accepted answer that is obsolete or broken?

Tags: support, obsolete-information

There are questions which have accepted answers but the answers are either irrelevant to the present day context (though the question is still relevant) or link to web pages that no longer exist.

Here is an example of a question answered with a dead link:

[Writing XFCE panel plugins in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758470/writing-xfce-panel-plugins-in-python)

Here is an example of a question answered with a solution that is no more applicable today (the answer targets an obsolete version of the subject application while the question does not specify the version):

[How to save files to different folders based on extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/271589/how-to-save-files-to-different-folders-based-on-extension)

I am interested in getting up-to-date answer to both the questions. Can they be reopened?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is; the questions in question are open. They have accepted answers, sure, but that doesn't mean other answers can't be written

Answer (score 4):

They're not "closed"... the questions can still be answered.

If you have sufficient reputation, you can put a bounty on the questions to draw attention to them and ask for an updated answer. One of the bounty reasons is even

> **Current answers are outdated**
>   The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

If an answer no longer actually answers a question - for example, the link that was used to answer it no longer works and there's not sufficient information in the question to surmise an alternate - you can flag it as not an answer and (if a moderator agrees), the answer will be deleted.

Comment: What if I'm a new user without enough rep to put a bounty?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287356/how-can-i-bump-other-users-unanswered-questions